# Postman not working after updating Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, postman

When I start Postman I see the icon appear in the Dock and in the Force Quit window, and I can click on the icon in the dock and Postman appears in the menu bar, with the single option "Quit Postman." So it's running, but the window doesn't appear. This morning I upgraded Chrome to 55.0.2883.95, Chromium to 58.0.2991.0, and Chrome Canary is at 58.0.2990.0.

Is there a way to switch Postman from Chrome to Chromium or Chrome Canary (i.e., to test Postman with different builds)? Or to revert Chrome to any older build? Or any other ideas to get Postman working?

Answer (score 1):

The chrome addon for Postman will be [depricated](http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/08/23/using-the-postman-chrome-app-implications-from-the-recent-google-announcement/) soon.

There are now fully functional standalone apps for Windows/Mac/Linux [here](https://www.getpostman.com/apps).  They work just as well as the Chrome addon and even have some additional features.  I would suggest moving to the standalone apps.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome I googled "Postman," which took me to the Chrome App store, and the Postman page has a green button for "Launch App Now." That worked!

Answer (score 0):

try disable and then enable the extension. 
It worked for me. 
Sometimes google chrome doesn't load it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a nearly similar problem, where Chrome postman app (extension) fails to post/get/etc. It was unable to access the internet for some reason. After trying many solutions, it seems that the javascript setting in Chrome was causing it. You need to enable javascript in Chrome, restart Chrome, then the postman app will work.